# Crash on returning from C: Why (of course)?

Tags: c#, c, interop

In C#  I fill a binary buffer (1.5 to 2 kB), to which I refer in a C DLL. All goes well (stepping through C says so), until I have to return to C#. At that very last moment, the program crashes (NO exception throwing, just a crash: "Stopped working").
Cr is the C routine, in a DLL.
I work in Visual Studio Community 2017.
Earlier, I passed the data via a string and sscanf_s in C, which worked well,  but wanted to speed up things a bit (and learn different things on the way).
The buffer contains all kinds of floats, ints and doubles, which are picked up C-side correctly (stepping says so). 
Here is the first piece of C# code:

```
    double[,] MemberEndforces = new double[mbCount, 12];
            double[,] Deflection = new double[mbCount + 1, 6];
            //double[] Reactions = new double[6];

            unsafe
            {
                using (BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream()))
                {

                    BuildExportBuffer(binWriter);
                    var buffer = ((MemoryStream)binWriter.BaseStream).GetBuffer();
                    info = NativeMethods.Cr(
                        ref buffer, NrOfMod, Eigenfreqs, ref error,
                        ref rms_resid, MemberEndforces, Deflection);
                }  // end using
                if (info != 0)
                    throw new MyException(string.Format(ErrorMessages.SomeError, info));
                bool converged = error < tolerance;

                ...
            } // end unsafe
```

And here folllows the head of the receiving C-routine. Only at the last curly brace, and stepping back to C#, does the crash occur. It does so, with or without the safe{} block.

```
extern "C"
{
    char ** buffer;
    //char * next_token;

    __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Cr(
        char **_buffer,
        int n,
        float * eigenFreq,
        double * error,
        double * rms_resid,
        double * endforces,
        double * deflection
         )
     { buffer = _buffer;
        ...
        // read stuff from  buffer and process it...
        return ExitCode;

     }
```

And here is the DLL import:

```
[DllImport(@"Cr.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "Cr", 
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping =false,ThrowOnUnmappableChar =true)]


    public static extern int Cr([In] ref byte[] buffer,
        [In] int n, 
        float[] eigenfreq, 
        ref double error, 
        ref double rms_resid,            
        double[,] force,
        double[,] defl);
```

So: Why? What do I do wrong ? If there's something wrong in the C-part, it would have shown earlier than the last curly brace, no? The last part of the C code does a lot of freeing malloc-ed blocks (not the buffer!).

Comment: Without seeing the dllImport and the concrete exception is very hard to any one to help you

Comment: Here you are , the DLLImport.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6d1322ce-b1e6-4da4-92cf-366259510e48/passing-multidimensional-array-from-c-to-win32-c-dll?forum=clr) on MSDN multidimensional arrays aren't marshaled when calling an external function, so you must convert the array to a single dimensional one.

As I see those arrays are output buffers, so for calling you can do this:

```
double[] MemberEndforces = new double[mbCount * 12];
double[] Deflection = new double[(mbCount + 1) * 6];

//...

info = NativeMethods.Cr(
                    ref buffer, NrOfMod, Eigenfreqs, ref error,
                    ref rms_resid, MemberEndforces, Deflection);
```

Then you need to convert those arrays to multidimensional ones once the function has been called:

```
double[,] mMemberEndforces = new double[mbCount, 12];
double[,] mDeflection = new double[mbCount + 1, 6];

for(int x = 0; x < mbCount; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 12; y++)
        mMemberEndforces[x,y] = MemberEndforces[x * 12 + y];
}

for(int x = 0; x < mbCount + 1; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
        mDeflection[x,y] = Deflection[x * 6 + y];
}
```

Comment: I wrote the arrays element by element, one at a time, to the buffer. So the buffer has no clue that there is an array in it. C-Side, I read the arrays again element by element into C-arrays, knowing exactly what went into the buffer. The arrays that I return (Deflection and MemberEndForces, defined C#-side, filled C-side), came back OK when i had a string buffer, so that cannot be an issue, could it?

Comment: @Erik I can't see what your external function does, my cristal ball is under repair right now... In any case C# will not marshal correctly multidimensional arrays so it will fail, also adding the exception you receive may be of help, here on Stack Overflow we are programmers not crystal gazers...

Comment: Of course the problem might be somewhere in the C-function, but the thing is, that function seems to work well UNTIL returning to C#. Stepping shows the C part works, the data is read correctly from the binary buffer.  Besides, using a StringBuilder buffer works like a charm, returning the C# arrays Deflection and  MemberEndForces in excelent condition. Not surprising, since I only pass pointers,.
From what you say I can, for now,  only conclude, that there is nothing wrong with what I do and I have to look elsewhere. That helps too.

Comment: @Erik Again, C# WILL NOT marshall correctly the multidimensional arrays. If you post the exception you receive may be I can confirm if that's the problem.

Comment: As I said before: no exception, just:
"MyProgram has stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.
Windows will close the program and notify you is a solution is available"
and a button: "Close program".
Of course there is no subsequent notification.

Comment: @Erik Are you running this in debug mode?

Comment: Yes.
Strange, that the the byte[] did work and the ref byte[] did not, but only when returning to C#.
INSIDE C, it did work.
Anyway, I got the solution, as you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
I removed the unsafe{}. It's not necessary.
Then I "de-referenced" ref buffer in the call to the C-routine:

```
 using (BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream()))
 {
     BuildExportBuffer(binWriter); // fill the buffer with doubles and floats ant ints
     var buffer = ((MemoryStream)binWriter.BaseStream).GetBuffer(); // get the buffer's address
     info = NativeMethods.Cr( buffer, NrOfMod, Eigenfreqs, ref error, ref rms_resid,
 MemberEndforces, Deflection);
  .....
    etc.
```

Same thing in the DLLImport, of course.

Also in the C-function I changed some little things:

```
extern "C"
{
char ** buffer;

__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Cr(
    char *_buffer,  // <== here and
    int n,
    float * eigenFreq,
    double * error,
    double * rms_resid,
    double * endforces,
    double * deflection
     )
 {

    buffer = &_buffer; // <== here.
```

To show how I read a double from the buffer C-side:

```
double  readd(char **buffer)
{
   double *f = (double *) *buffer;
   *buffer += 8;
   return *f;
}
```

Works like a charm. I still have to figure out the WHY.